# Filtering Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I have this Pivot Table, and what I need to do is: Filter this data and show only those records whose date (3rd column) is equal to its parent date (2nd column) or just 1 day difference is there.

And then I have to put conditional formatting on the values (Columns after 3rd column) based on 'If both dates are same and the value lies in particular column'

How to do that?
Currently I have to do it manually, so looking for a solution if anyone could help. 
Thanks in advance

[image: ScreenShot of Pivot Table]

Comment: You can do the filtering with helper column in the original range (`=ABS(ChildDate - ParentDate)<=1`). Regarding conditional formatting, your question isn't clear please specify what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: The parent date is not mentioned in the same row, it's mentioned many rows above the child row....

Comment: I meant helper column in the source of the pivot table.

Comment: Oh...Actually, there are multiple Pivot Tables from the same source data so I'm looking if I can do directly from the Pivot Table without messing up the source data

Comment: No, you can't do it in the pivot. Actually it doesn't change anything in the source data, just add a new column, so it shouldn't be a problem.